# Parskip messes up levels in a tree generated by chunk and bundle

Tags: parskip

This document that generates a dummy-tree. However, the right-most branch becomes lowered if \usepackage{parskip} is included (shown in picture further down). I want parskip for other parts. Any suggestion to fix this without removing parskip is greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book} 
%
\usepackage{ecltree,epic,multicol}
\usepackage{parskip} % COMMENTING OUT THIS LINE REMOVES THE ISSUE

\begin{document}

\begin{bundle}{Level-1}
        \chunk{\begin{bundle}{Level-2A}
                        \chunk{Level-3A}
               \end{bundle}
               }
        \chunk{\begin{bundle}{Level-2B}
                \chunk{Level-3B}
                \chunk{\begin{bundle}{Level-3C}
                        \chunk{Level-4A}
                        \chunk{Level-4B}
                       \end{bundle}
                       }
                \end{bundle}
               }
\end{bundle}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you want to continue using `ecltree` (which is by now 30 years old), or would you be willing to switch to other tree drawing packages?

Comment: Thanks! I have quite a lot of such trees, so most likely I will stick with it.

Answer (score 2):

You could set parskip to zero locally (if you are committed to using this package)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book} 
%
\usepackage{ecltree,epic,multicol}
\usepackage{parskip} % COMMENTING OUT THIS LINE REMOVES THE ISSUE

\begin{document}

{\parskip=0pt\begin{bundle}{Level-1}
        \chunk{\begin{bundle}{Level-2A}
                        \chunk{Level-3A}
               \end{bundle}
               }
        \chunk{\begin{bundle}{Level-2B}
                \chunk{Level-3B}
                \chunk{\begin{bundle}{Level-3C}
                        \chunk{Level-4A}
                        \chunk{Level-4B}
                       \end{bundle}
                       }
                \end{bundle}
               }
\end{bundle}
}

\begin{bundle}{Level-1}
        \chunk{\begin{bundle}{Level-2A}
                        \chunk{Level-3A}
               \end{bundle}
               }
        \chunk{\begin{bundle}{Level-2B}
                \chunk{Level-3B}
                \chunk{\begin{bundle}{Level-3C}
                        \chunk{Level-4A}
                        \chunk{Level-4B}
                       \end{bundle}
                       }
                \end{bundle}
               }
\end{bundle}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked - thanks!